# No place to put HD audio cable on motherboard

Tags: audio, motherboard, case

I have manualy put togheter my PC but something strange happend.

I’ve got an ASUS H110M-R/C/SI, Socket 1151 (Bulk) and my case is a DeepCool TESSERACT SW ATX Mid Tower.

From which left one cable: An HD Audio cable.

The cable itself comes from the audio jack on the front top of the box and I couldn’t find where to put it in the motherboard.

I find the documentation of the motherboard where it was said that the board supports HD Audio.

The pins look something like this:

```
.....
... .
```

This is what the cable looks like:

[image]

[Here](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/H110M-R/E11428_H110M-R_UM_V2_WEB.pdf?_ga=1.256426059.1563934167.1480415401) I think is the documentation.

Comment: Most Asus motherboards use a shared port for front panel audio, you get either standard or HD audio, and it is controlled in the BIOS... if you connect an HD Audio header, you set the BIOS to HD Audio, if you connect a traditional analog audio header you leave it at default. These are usually just handled through the front panel connector, what type of cable are you trying to connect?

Comment: The cable you are showing is just an extension cable for the front panel connector, needed in some applications and not others, if your case's cable fit, you don't need that extension cable.

Comment: I think you want #7 in the diagram in the manual

Comment: Well extension or not this is the only cabel that left unpluged from the case  and the audio jaks on top of the case do not work : /

Comment: The cabel does not seems to fit in #7.

Comment: @lazarov Did you change the audio mode in the BIOS to HD Audio?

Comment: you want #12 labeled "AAFP" (page 9 aka page 1-1) which, two pages later is incorrectly stated as #11, but if you note, #11 information states it is 10-1 pins and is an AAFP

Comment: @Yorik I will give it a try on AAFP.

Comment: @acejavelin well I have not I was not aware that I shoud change the audio mode I will research on doing that as well

Comment: this should be it http://i.imgur.com/Xn055rT.jpg  Does this pic exactly match your motherboard? Can you find an image of your exact mobo, if not? Seems the H110 line of boards, most offer it, but the specific R/C/SI model may not have it if that is not your mobo

Comment: @Yorik you were correct !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want #12 labeled "AAFP" (page 9 aka page 1-1) which, two pages later is incorrectly stated as #11, but if you note, #11 information states it is 10-1 pins and is an AAFP

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't ask a question, the assumption is you are asking where the front panel cable connects to the motherboard.

I couldn't find the exact manual for your board because of the region I live in, but I looked at the manual to a similar board with the same socket.

You will need to look on the board for a connector for the front panel, or `F_PANEL`. The below image is from the ASUS manual I found. It should be similar to yours.

[image]

Comment: I recently built a new machine with an ASUS board and the audio header was on the bottom right as well. Regardless, it should be listed in the manual which hopefully the OP kept . . .

Comment: "Connector for the front panel, `F_PANEL` is the power and activity LEDs, reset switch, power switch.  Audio is on a different connector.